Jankstats or dumpsys gfxinfo which is more accurate
My Android app is multi screen app having native and web components. I want to measure UI performance for my app. I measure UI performance for my app on CI pipeline for nightly builds and if I see any breach in benchmark (eg if Janky frames are more than 10%) then I debug and take action.
I used these 2 methods for measurement - dumpsys gfxinfo and jankstats
Observation:
userflow and test content are same for both methods but dumpsys gfxinfo always shows 50% + total frames rendered and 30-50% more janky frames
What is difference between jankstats and dumpsys gfxinfo ?
Which method is more reliable? which one shall i consider for my tests ?
